# dplyr: use aggregated group_by results in original dataframe

Tags: r, dplyr

I have this dataset:

```
test1 <- data.frame(
  group = rep(c("X", "Y", "Z"), each = 3),
  A = seq(from = 0.15, to = 0.55, by = 0.05),
  B = 5:13)

  group    A  B
1     X 0.15  5
2     X 0.20  6
3     X 0.25  7
4     Y 0.30  8
5     Y 0.35  9
6     Y 0.40 10
7     Z 0.45 11
8     Z 0.50 12
9     Z 0.55 13
```

I want to use group_by to get the average of A by group:

```
test2 <- test1 %>% 
  group_by(group) %>% 
  summarise(avg = mean(A))

  group   avg
  <fct> <dbl>
1 X      0.2 
2 Y      0.35
3 Z      0.5
```

Now my question: Is there a way to cast these aggregated results back into the original dataframe without having to use a merge? That is, in test1, I want a column with the averages per group. Like this:

```
  group    A  B  avg
1     X 0.15  5 0.20
2     X 0.20  6 0.20
3     X 0.25  7 0.20
4     Y 0.30  8 0.35
5     Y 0.35  9 0.35
6     Y 0.40 10 0.35
7     Z 0.45 11 0.50
8     Z 0.50 12 0.50
9     Z 0.55 13 0.50
```

As said, I'm currently merging these two dataframes back together, but that seems a little inefficient?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `mutate` instead of `summarise`:

```
library("dplyr")

test1 <- data.frame(
    group = c(rep("X", 3), rep("Y", 3), rep("Z", 3)),
    A = seq(from = 0.15, to = 0.55, by = 0.05),
    B = 5:13
)

test2 <- test1 %>% 
    group_by(group) %>% 
    mutate(avg = mean(A))
```